# LightGBM Error - length not same as data

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm

I am using lightGBM for finding feature importance but I am getting error `LightGBMError: b'len of label is not same with #data'` .
 X.shape
    (73147, 12) 
      y.shape
    (73147,)

Code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import lightgbm as lgb

# Initialize an empty array to hold feature importances
feature_importances = np.zeros(X.shape[1])

# Create the model with several hyperparameters
model = lgb.LGBMClassifier(objective='binary', boosting_type = 'goss', n_estimators = 10000, class_weight = 'balanced')

# Fit the model twice to avoid overfitting
for i in range(2):

    # Split into training and validation set
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = i)

    # Train using early stopping
    model.fit(X, y_train, early_stopping_rounds=100, eval_set = [(X_test, y_test)], 
              eval_metric = 'auc', verbose = 200)

    # Record the feature importances
    feature_importances += model.feature_importances_
```

See screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: @desertnaut Any idea why I am getting the error ?

Comment: @desertnaut How can fix that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a typo in your code; instead of

```
model.fit(X, y_train, [...])
```

it should be

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, [...])
```

As it is now, it is understandable that the length of `X` and `y_train` is not the same, hence your error.